# Typo3 close and start a new paragraph <p> in each <br /> in bodytext at news extension

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I'm using Typo3 9.5.14 and CkEditor to add and edit news articles, i see in frontend that it is closing and starting a new paragraph at every 
 in the bodytext area here an example :

```
<p>
Text somthing <br />
Text somthing 2 <br />
Text somthing 3 <br />
Text somthing 4 <br />
</p>
```

After save, i see in frontend is converted to this;

```
<p>Text somthing </p>
<p>Text somthing 2 </p>
<p>Text somthing 3 </p>
<p>Text somthing 4 </p>
```

But in source it is still in the original code even after save.
Is it really because CKEditor and how can i prevent this ?

This is causing the problem of adding new spaces between each line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back with the solution i find, i have uninstalled the obsolete extension rtehtmlarea, and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly switch to direct source editing?

[image]

The other reason could be you need to allow 
 tags in the editor configuration. Like this :

[TYPO3 9.5.4 CKEditor RTE deletes style attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741464/typo3-9-5-4-ckeditor-rte-deletes-style-attributes)

Hope it helps you

EDIT:

Does this setting still work in TYPO3 9? maybe that is it:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/7.6/en-us/Rte/Transformations/Tsconfig/Index.html#dontconvbrtoparagraph

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in source still the same original code so maybe this is not because ckeditor ? maybe this is because Typo3 rendering html ?

Comment: maybe try disable the ckeditor in extensions, see if it works, not sure